# Android Notification action button

Tags: android

I try action in my Notification click a button from "builder", but I can't.

I read documentation oficial :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    // Show controls on lock screen even when user hides sensitive content.
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)

    // Add media control buttons that invoke intents in your media service
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "Previous", prevPendingIntent) // #0 HERE A BUTTON
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause", pausePendingIntent)  // #1 HERE A BUTTON
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", nextPendingIntent)     // #2 HERE A BUTTON

    // Apply the media style template
    .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
    .setShowActionsInCompactView(1 /* #1: pause button */)
    .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken())
    .setContentTitle("Wonderful music")
    .setContentText("My Awesome Band")
    .setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap)
    .build();
```

I see this post :

[Android, get Notifications Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558048/android-get-notifications-responses)

And someone say :

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Notification n = sbn.getNotification();
    for(Action action : n.actions){
        String title = action.title.toString;
        ...
    }
}
```

But I can't use because I not extends of "NotificationListenerService" I extends of IntentService

How I can click Buttons and after occurs a event ?

Any can know differences about NotificationListenerService and IntentService ?

I hope explain correctly

Comment: See this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350998/determine-addaction-click-for-android-notifications?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

i was created the my Custom notification by Custom Message and Drawable Image to Notify and also added the handler while user was clicked on Notification to open the New Screen.

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message,
        String pid, String type) {
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);



        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                AddFriendRequestActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("screen", "noti");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("friendId", pid);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("MeetAtAirport").setContentText(message).build();
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.custom_notification);// set your custom layout
        contentView
                .setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "MeetAtAirport");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
        notification.bigContentView = contentView;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final int noteId = 1232;

        notificationManager.notify(noteId, notification);


}
```

There is one Notification Layout as Follows with name as R.layout.custom_notification:

`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/txtHelvBold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    style="@style/txtHelvBold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image" />
```

`

In this Layout File You are able to add your Buttons and handle the Button's Click as Other are used in above code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, but ... where is button ? ".addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "Previous", prevPendingIntent)", my problem is similar to here https://udinic.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/adding-more-actions-to-jellybean-notifications/

Comment: We should have to Checked out that api level and based on that we have to set the Notification Layout.

Comment: Your idea is good, but how I can "Button = (LinearLayout)context.findViewById(R.id.Button);"  ???

Comment: we are able to access Button by Button btn = (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.button); and now we also used btn.setOnClickListner();

Comment: Wait wait wait ... "RemoteViews contentView "  you know about remoteviews ? .... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

Comment: You can achieve the on Click of button in Notification Layout with following code as : contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, 
            notificationIntent);

Comment: How I can "contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent" assing with button ? button = (Button)contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent.. and manage the event of the button itself ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Exemple of notification with Button
private static void scheduleNotificationWithButton(Context context, String message) {

    int notifReCode = 1;

    //What happen when you will click on button
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    //Button
    NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Go", pendingIntent).build();

    //Notification
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Back to Application ?")
            .setContentTitle("Amazing news")
            .addAction(action) //add buton
            .build();

    //Send notification
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```